# Spivak's Calculus, Chapter 5, Problem 23

Tags: calculus, solution-verification

Someone asked this question before. However, it is still not clear to me how Spivak comes up with those hints.
[image]

[image]

The following is my take. However, I am not sure whether it is rigorous or not. Especially for the red sentence below, do I need to elaborate it more?
[image]

Answer (score 3):

**Case (1):** There exists some $\varepsilon > 0$ such that  $\lvert f(x)\rvert > \varepsilon$ for all sufficiently small $x$.

In other words, there exists some $\varepsilon > 0$ and some $\delta > 0$ such that **for all $x$** if

$0<\lvert x\rvert < \delta$, then $\lvert f(x)\rvert > \varepsilon$

We can define $g(x)$ for these small $x$ as

$g(x) = \frac {1}{f(x)}$

(We know for these small x, the denominator is $\neq 0$, so no trouble there).

Now $\lim_{x \to 0} f(x)g(x) = \lim_{x \to 0}1 = 1$

So the limit of $f(x)g(x)$ exists. If $\lim_{x\to0}g(x)$ exists, then so too must the limit of $f(x)$ (Part a). Therefore the limit of $g(x)$ also does not exist.

**Edit:** How do we know $\lim_{x\to 0}g(x) \neq 0$, and hence part (a) applies?

Suppose $\lim_{x\to 0} g(x) = 0$

By our case(1) definition we have

$$\lim_{x\to 0} \frac{1}{f(x)} = 0$$

So for any $\varepsilon > 0$ there exists some $\delta > 0$ such that for all $x$ if

$$0 < |x| < \delta \text{ then } \left|\frac{1}{f(x)}\right| < \varepsilon$$.

Inverting we have
$$|f(x)| > \frac{1}{\varepsilon}$$

Rephrasing, for any $\frac{1}{\varepsilon} > 0$ there exists some $\delta > 0$ such that for all $x$ if

$$0 < |x| < \delta \text{ then } |{f(x)}| > \frac{1}{\varepsilon}$$.

This means $\lim_{x\to 0} |f(x)| = \infty$, a contradiction. (part(b) already covered that possibility).

**Case(2):** Here, unlike case(1), as $x$ approaches $0$, $f(x)$ gets arbitrarily small **for some x.**

To put this in $\varepsilon-\delta$ terms:

For each $\varepsilon > 0$ and for every $\delta > 0$ there is *some* x with

$0 < \lvert x\rvert < \delta$ and $\lvert f(x)\rvert < \varepsilon$

This looks very close to the definition of a limit; the key difference is that here, $\lvert f(x)\rvert < \varepsilon$ only for **some** of the x's in the specified $\delta$ region, not for all of them, and that we can always find such x's no matter how small we make $\delta$.

In other words, some values of $f(x)$ seem to be heading towards $0$ for very small $x$ and other values aren't.

Spivak's idea is to define $g(x)$ so that $g(x)f(x) = f(x)$ for the "well behaving" x's, and $0$ for everything else.

See if you can do this. Once you do, you'll see that for your $g(x)$, $\lim_{x \to 0} g(x)$ does not exist.

It might help to begin by considering a concrete example: $f(x) = sin(\frac{1}{x})$

Notice that as $x \rightarrow 0, f(x)$ fluctuates between $1$ and $-1$. $f(x) = 0$ when $x = \frac{1}{k\pi}$ where $k$ is an integer.

As $k$ gets bigger, $x$ gets closer and closer to $0$ and $\lvert f(x)\rvert= 0$ over and over.

Can you define a function $g$ such that $g(x)f(x)$ emphasizes these $x = \frac{1}{k\pi}$ points, and "smooths out" the others?

Comment: Hey Ben, great answer! In order to apply (a) to **Case (1)** it is necessary to make sure that $\lim_{x\to0}g(x)\neq0$. I think this follows from the definition $g(x) = \frac {1}{f(x)}$ and the assumption that $\lim_{x\to0}\lvert f(x)\rvert =\infty$ does not hold, but I fail to prove this rigorously. How can we show that if $g(x) = \frac {1}{f(x)}$ and $\lim_{x\to0}\lvert f(x)\rvert =\infty$ does not hold, then $\lim_{x\to0}g(x)\neq0$?

Comment: Hi @Carlevaro99. I expanded on that just now in my answer. Just look for the edit in the case(1) section. Easier adding there vs. trying to put it in the comments :) It took me a while to re-understand this problem. It's tricky one with all those different cases!

Comment: IIRC I had to consult the answer book myself when I originally tried to do this problem. One of those, "it's cool when you get it, but no way I would have thought to do that on my own" problems, of which Spivak is rife.

Comment: @Ben Sorry for the late reply but could you explain why there are 2 cases in the first place? I thought the 2nd case was when $lim_{x \to 0}f(x) = 0$ but would that not imply there is $\delta > 0$ such that for $0<|x|<\delta$, $|f(x)| < \varepsilon$ for every $\varepsilon >0$?

Comment: @Eggue OP's question centered on part (c) of the problem. The two parts in my answer correspond to the two parts in Spivak's hint for part(c).

Comment: @Eggue However, you are right that the case where $\lim_{x \to 0} f(x) = 0$ does seem to be missing from my answer. Case (2) of Spivak's hint actually covers this possibility, despite what I said about $f$ not actually going to zero. For Case (2), we create a $g$ with value $0$ everywhere, except at points $x$ where $f$ is "well behaving". At these well behaving $x$'s, we make $g(x) = 1$. Here $\lim_{x\to0}g(x)$ doesn't exist but  $\lim_{x\to0}fg$ does. This sort of $g$ that fluctuates between $0$ and $1$, also works for the case where $\lim_{x \to 0} f(x) = 0$.

Comment: @Eggue In other words, Spivak's case (2) is more general than the case where $\lim_{x\to0}f(x) = 0$. His case (2) has $f$ getting arbitrarily small for some but not necessarily all $x \to 0$. It turns out this is enough.

Comment: So do both cases in Spivak's hint correspond to $\lim_{x \to 0} f(x)$ not existing? If so i'm not sure why the distinction was made between them. Why wouldn't letting $g(x) = \frac{1}{f(x)}$ suffice for case (2)?

Comment: @Eggue For case (1) in the hint, we can define $g$ such that for sufficiently small $x$, $g=1/f$ because, by assumption, we know for these sufficiently small $x$, $f\neq 0$. This is not necessarily true for case (2).

Comment: @Eggue In case (2), all we know about $f$ is that we can always find at least *some* $x$ arbitrarily close to $0$ such that the value of $f$ can be made arbitrarily small. In my OG answer, I phrased it poorly. I should have said for case (2) that $\lim_{x\to0}f(x)$ might be zero, or the limit might not exist, but we know at least that for any $\varepsilon > 0$ and for any $\delta > 0$ there exists at least *some* $x$ such that both $|x| < \delta$ and $|f(x)| < \varepsilon$ are true.